# How to use the same key to flip multiple times in PsychoPy?

Tags: python, psychopy

I’m trying to use the same key to flip after multiple successive stimuli in PsychoPy but it keeps flipping successive screens as well then.

What I came up with was the following slight modification of one of the examples in the manual:

```py
from psychopy import visual, core, event

win = visual.Window(monitor="testMonitor", units="deg")

stim1 = visual.TextStim(win, text="Stim 1", pos=(0,0))
stim2 = visual.TextStim(win, text="Stim 2", pos=(0,0))
stim3 = visual.TextStim(win, text="Stim 3", pos=(0,0))

while len(event.getKeys(['space'])) <= 0:
    stim1.draw()
    win.flip()

event.clearEvents()
print(event.getKeys()) # test if key buffer is really empty
win.flip()

# while len(event.getKeys(['return'])) <= 0:
#     stim2.draw()
#     win.flip()

# event.clearEvents()
# win.flip()

while len(event.getKeys(['space'])) <= 0:
    stim3.draw()
    win.flip()

event.clearEvents()
win.flip()

win.close()
core.quit()
```

However if I hit space on the first screen, it doesn’t just flip this screen. Instead it will flash `stim3` for a split second and then immediately terminate. If on the other hand I use a different key for the second stimulus (replace `'space'` with `'return'` in the loop condition), that works fine.

My first suspicion was that `event.clearEvents()` somehow failed to clear the event buffer, so the space event from the first stimulus remained saved and also flipped the second stimulus. However in that case the `stim3` shouldn’t be shown at all because the loop condition would immediately fail. Also, if I print out `event.getKeys()` at the indicated position above, it appears to be empty. Moreover, if I use a different key **between** the two space-triggered stimuli (remove comments from the `stim2` section), suddenly all keys work just fine.

Does anybody have an idea what I’m doing wrong?

(Btw if you’re wondering: I modified the manual example by changing the loop where the program waits for input from a `while True` loop into `while len(event.getKeys(['space'])) <= 0` which eliminates the need of using the exact same condition to `break`. I tested it with the original idiom just to be sure and the behaviour is the exact same as with my version.)

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing found that deleting the `win.flip()`'s after each `event.clearEvent()` fixes the issue. I’m not quite sure why the additional flips (which I thought were necessary to clear the screen before drawing the new stimulus) would cause such a behaviour though. Can somebody explain?